# JS / Chrome extension - Как отменить срабатывание скрипта на странице при нажатии левой кнопки мыши?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Например в вк, как при нажатии на картинку отменить её открывание, или переключение на другую?

```
.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  и ретерн фолс не помогает return false
});
```

Ничего из этого не работает.

Comment: `Event#preventDefault`?

Comment: @Skyrocker event.preventDefault(); ?  не работает, все равно выполняется открытие картинки в вк при нажатии левой кноки мыши

Comment: Там смотреть надо, вряд ли там так просто, я предложил очевидное. Вам надо посмотреть что именно нужно, вытащить проблемный участок на обозрение, а так - вряд ли кто полезет сам экспериментировать для Вас.